# Problema con trigger al actualizar la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

No puedo conseguir que a través de la Base de Datos MySQL pueda controlar que se inserte todo en mayúsculas, o actualizar después de insertar.

Tengo el siguiente trigger en la tabla `paises`(`idPasi`, `pais`):

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `tf-modelo-de-datos`.`paises_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `paises` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tf.paises SET pais = UPPER(pais);
END
```

Pero al insertar un nuevo país me tira el siguiente error:

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. Executing: INSERT INTO `tf`.`paises` (`pais`) VALUES
>   ('Argentina');
>
> ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'paises' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger. SQL Statement: INSERT INTO `tf`.`paises`
>   (`pais`) VALUES ('Argentina')

Leí algo de que se estaba tratando de modificar el mismo dato dos veces al mismo tiempo.

¿Alguien conoce alguna forma de hacer éste control de la forma más eficiente posible, pero a nivel de Base de Datos?.

Comment: no tenes que hacerlo before_insert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No puedes de ningún modo actualizar la misma tabla a la que afecta el trigger, por que esto generaría una recursión infinita. Pero lo que puedes hacer es,  modificar la "pseudo" tabla  `NEW` para ajustar el valor de la columna en cuestión, solo que debes hacerlo antes del `INSERT`, es decir colgarte del `BEFORE INSERT`.

Ejemplo:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Paises;

CREATE TABLE Paises (
  Nombre varchar(255)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trg_Paises BEFORE INSERT ON Paises
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.Nombre = UPPER(NEW.Nombre);
END
;

INSERT INTO Paises (Nombre) VALUE('argentina');
```

[Aquí el Fiddle](http://rextester.com/HSTV32301)

Comment: Elimine la mía , creía que era comentario que estoy con el móvil. Pedazo respuesta clara y formativa. Gracias !!

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Patricio, ¡funcionó!.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que utilizar `BEFORE INSERT` y utilizar el objeto `NEW` (para el registro que estás actualizando) y el objeto `OLD` (el registro anterior).

```
CREATE TRIGGER lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.pais = UPPER(NEW.pais );
```

Espero servir de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda Antonio.