# MySQL - trigger para generar un codigo md5

Tags: mysql, trigger, update

He estado intentando usar un disparador para actualizar un registro luego de haberlo ingresado, el problema es que no me funciona el siguiente código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `test_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `chat_test_trigger` 
FOR EACH ROW UPDATE chat_test_trigger SET id_chat_enc = md5(id_chat)
```

Lo que necesito es que luego de que ingrese un registro, agarre el autoincrementable que acaba de asignar y lo encripte en md5 y lo asigne a un campo de ese mismo registro.

El problema es que me tira este error cuando ingreso una nueva fila:

> #1442 - Can't update table 'chat_test_trigger' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Cualquier consejo es bien recibido, gracias.

Comment: No puedes actualizar la misma tabla afectada por el trigger, revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195874/controlar-que-se-inserte-todo-en-may%C3%BAscula

Comment: Como no puedes actualizar la misma tabla en un trigger definido sobre ella misma, como comenta @PatricioMoracho, tendrías que usar identificadores generados por ti mismo en lugar de una columna autoincrementable. También te digo que tener un valor encriptado en md5 ya de por sí es poco seguro y si, encima, lo haces sobre un valor que aparece en el mismo registro, pues no tiene demasiado sentido

Comment: Hola, gracias por los comentarios, al final tuve que hacer un update luego del insert debido alos obstaculos que me mencionaron. Con respecto al valor del mismo registro era para hacer una prueba rapida, pensaba luego cambiarlo a AES que me parece la mejor opcion. Sin embargo muchas gracias por la ayuda.